# Get page id by template

Tags: pages, templates

I want to know if it's possible to get the ID of a page with a specific template. Is this possible to get the ID of a page that assigned to "page-special.php"?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

When a page is created, the assigned template to that page is saved as custom post meta in the same way as custom fields. The `meta_key` is `_wp_page_template` and the `meta_value` will be the page template

You can simply make use of [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages) to retrieve all pages which have a `meta_value` of the specified template

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-special.php'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->ID.'<br />';
}
```

### EDIT 23-07-2015

If one just needs the page ids, then you make use of `get_posts` and then just pass `page` as `post_type` and 'ids`as`fields` value. This will ensure a much faster, much more optimized query as we will only return the post id column in the db and not all of them for the given pages

(*Requires PHP 5.4+*)

```
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'fields' => 'ids',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-special.php'
];
$pages = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $pages as $page ) 
    echo $page . '</br>';
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Isn't a bit too "heavy"? (running through all the pages)

Comment: Depends on how many pages you have. There is actually no faster native way that I know of to retrieve this data. If you have a lot of pages, I would suggest that you make use of transients to store that data and only flush/delete the transient when a new page is published

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help. Enjoy :-)

Comment: @user3800799 I have updated the post if you are only interested in getting the ids, nothing else

Comment: You could also use `set_transient` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) if you don't want to query the database too much.

Comment: @ChrisAndersson Unless you have hundreds of pages, setting a transient will be pretty useless here. My code perform only one superfast db query as we only query post ID's which dramatically increase performance. Transients perform two db calls every page load, although it might be a tad faster. Transients are only useful on expensive operations

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for :). I have a blog template that I include in my theme...it's very useful to get the page id of the page assigned to the blog template, rather than having to manually input it every time!

Answer (score 6):

If your page template resides inside sub-folder, theme-folder/page-templates/page-template.php then you below query will works:

```
$page_details = get_pages( array(
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
 'hierarchical' => 0,
 'meta_value' => 'page-templates/page-template.php'
));
```

This above codes also display sub-pages as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete function that works with WPML and Polylang. Credit to https://github.com/cyrale/

```
/**
* Search for a page with a particular template.
*
* @param string $template Template filename.
* @param array  $args     (Optional) See also get_posts() for example parameter usage.
* @param bool   $single   (Optional) Whether to return a single value.
*
* @return Will be an array of WP_Post if $single is false. Will be a WP_Post object if the page is find, FALSE otherwise
*/
if (!function_exists('get_page_by_template')) {
    function get_page_by_template($template, $args = array(), $single = true) {
        $pages_by_template = wp_cache_get('pages_by_template', 'cyrale');
        if (empty($pages_by_template) || !is_array($pages_by_template)) {
            $pages_by_template = array();
        }
        if (!isset($pages_by_template[$template])) {
            $args = wp_parse_args(array(
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'post_type'      => 'page',
                'suppress_filters'  => 0,
                'meta_query'     => array(
                    array(
                        'key'   => '_wp_page_template',
                        'value' => $template,
                    ),
                ),
            ), $args);
            $pages = get_posts($args);
            $pages_by_template[$template]= array(
                'single' => !empty($pages) && is_array($pages) ? reset($pages) : false,
                'pages'  => $pages,
            );
        }
        wp_cache_set('pages_by_template', $pages_by_template, 'cyrale');
        return $pages_by_template[$template][$single ? 'single' : 'pages'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is a slightly more articulated script that take into account a language, if needed. NOTE that it assumes the usage of Polylang, not WPML.

```
function get_post_id_by_template($template,$lang_slug = null){
  global $wpdb;
  $wh = ($lang_slug) ? " AND t.slug = %s" : "";

  $query = $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DISTINCT p.ID
    FROM $wpdb->posts p
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta meta ON meta.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships tr ON meta.post_id = tr.object_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms t ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
    WHERE p.post_status = 'publish' AND meta.meta_key = %s AND meta.meta_value = %s" . $wh,
    '_wp_page_template',
    $template,
    $lang_slug
  );

  $ids = $wpdb->get_results($query);

  if($ids && isset($ids[0])){
    $p = $ids[0];
    return $p->ID;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}// get_post_id_by_template
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
function kavkaz_get_page($page_template_filename){
    
    $pages = get_pages( array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => $page_template_filename
    ) );

    $url = null;
    
    if(isset($pages[0])) {
        $url = $pages[0]->guid;
    }
    
    return esc_url( $url );
}
```

Comment: That looks about the same as the top two answers, a get_pages() search for the meta_key? I also think ->guid is wrong: it might be the URL, but that's not guaranteed.  Instead I'd pass the page object (or just the ID) to get_permalink().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can query the postmeta table directly:

```
global $wpdb;
$template = 'page-special';
$sql = "select post_id from {$wpdb->postmeta} where meta_key = '{$template}.php'";
$pages = $wpdb->get_col($sql);
var_dump($pages);
```